# How can I tell if a virtual machine is up from the command line?

Tags: virtualbox

How can I tell from the command line if a specific virtual machine is up and running from the command line?

Comment: `vboxmanage list runningvms`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
vboxmanage list vms
```

Dos not (anymore?) tells if the vm is runing or not. It list also not running ones.

```
vboxmanage showvminfo "your_vm_name" | grep -c "running (since"
```

Will returns 1 if it's running, or 0 if not.

Comment: Also, `if ! VBoxManage showvminfo VMNAME --machinereadable | egrep '^VMState="poweroff"$' > /dev/null; then ...`

Comment: on Windows use `vboxmanage showvminfo "vmname or GUID" | findstr /c:"running (since"`

Comment: `vboxmanage list runningvms`

Answer (score 20):

If you want a list of all VMs to see if they are running or not use this command:

```
vboxmanage list vms --long | grep -e "Name:" -e "State:"
```

This will show the VMs name in one line and its status in the following line such as in

```
Name:            windows10pro
State:           running (since 2017-06-09T09:16:46.593000000)
Name:            ubuntu16LTS
State:           powered off (since 2017-02-09T19:11:33.000000000)
Name:            zammad
State:           running (since 2017-06-09T09:08:13.871000000)
```

Comment: The output from this includes info on any shared folders you might have set up. Pipe to another grep to remove it: `... | grep -v -e 'Host path:'`

Comment: This also shows PAUSED machines, "list runningvms" thinks that  paused machines are running which can be a little confusing...

Answer (score 13):

This command outputs the list of running vms (tested on Virtualbox  5.1)

```
VBoxManage list runningvms
```

To know if a vm is running, this command should do the job (return 1 if running, 0 otherwise) :

```
VBoxManage list runningvms | sed -r 's/^"(.*)".*$/\1/' | grep 'VM Name' | wc -l
```

Comment: A paused machine shows up as running with "list runningvms" this can be rather confusing when troubleshooting!

Answer (score 2):

Combining [`VBoxManage list runningvms`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-list) with `grep` *alone* without anything else will not only give a console output, but will also provide the return code required for shell scripting needs.  The `grep` command will require the exact double quote for the VM in the case where a vm name is provided: example:

```
$ VBoxManage list runningvms |grep '"demo_vm"'
$ echo $?
1
```

For a running one

```
$ VBoxManage list runningvms |grep '"demo_vm_on"'
"demo_vm_on" {bbff5c0e-f8d4-4751-8d34-c53c4b191613}
$ echo $?
0
```

In the other answer where `sed` was used to eliminate the double quotes, or if the grep was done *without* the double quotes, false positives will be returned.  Demonstration:

```
$ VBoxManage list runningvms |grep demo_vm
"demo_vm_on" {bbff5c0e-f8d4-4751-8d34-c53c4b191613}
$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get this information using [VBoxManage](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) (command-line interface to VirtualBox).

You can use The [showvminfo command](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-showvminfo) for show information about a particular virtual machine.

> This is the same information as *VBoxManage list vms* would show
>   for all   virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

> root@yourshell#**vboxmanage list vms**

Also, see [this document.](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html)

Comment: This answer is wrong. Accordingly to http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html, you can get the *registered* vms, but the OP needs the vms those are up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Generic ps script:

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> if ( ! ( C:"Program Files"\Oracle\VirtualBox\vboxmanage showvminfo "vmname" | Select-String "running (since" ))
{
C:"Program Files"\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe --comment "vmname" --startvm "{vmguid}"
}

note: You can get vmguid by right clicking on a vm in virtualbox and creating a shortcut on desktop to start that vm.

Comment: if it is not running , start it.   using this for my nginx reverse proxy